# Extending default Header from react-navigation v5

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I'm going to create a custom Modal by using the Modal of React Native
But I really want to reuse the header from react-navigation.

Can you please tell me that is that possible to do?

Many thanks!!!

Comment: explain it a little more, what actually you want ?

Comment: @Muhammad I mean:
I knew that react-navigation already had a modal what is like a popup. But I don't want to create a router for each Modal.
So I want to implement a custom Modal by using React Native's Modal https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/modal
But is there any way to use the Header bar of React-Navigation Stack for my custom Modal please?

Comment: No, you cant use navigation stack header in your custom created modal, here another approach and that is use a custom header also and hide the visibility of react-navigation header

Comment: @Muhammad yes, I see. Thank for your support :)